# How to increment a view to Recyclerview item while the item is visible for like 2-3 seconds?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, timer

So, I have a recyclerview which consists of images and I want to show how many views the image got via server json.

So as the user scrolls and sees an image for 2+ seconds I want to call the api and increment the view of that particular item which is visible currently. Any help on how to achieve this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LinearLayoutManager in RecyclerView you can get an item position by using

```
int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
```

To detect scroll events in the RecyclerView, you need to add a scroll listener, `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` and with every item scroll maintain timestamp.

You can read this article explaining the same functionality   [Detecting List Items Observed by User](https://proandroiddev.com/detecting-list-items-perceived-by-user-8f164dfb1d05)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but suppose i get the position of the item - how do i use that to get the item data of the recycleview? like if i get position 2 of an image, how do i get imageid, imageurl etc data from adapter? so i can send it to my api

Comment: As you are passing all the data to RecyclerView adapter, you have to create a method that will return all the data on that item position. For Example



public Object getItemAtPosition(int position){
return adapterDataList.get(position);
}